# asp.net mvc 4 model issue (entity framework) - Multiple contexts to one database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am programming with asp.net mvc 4 and I am using the template that is created by default when you select internet application template so this comes with a model, AccountModels.cs under Models folder which is initialized like this (AccountModels.cs):

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

(...) // tables definition
```

but not I need to add to the same database created by default some tables that stores my app configuration but I do not want creates my config tables within the default file created AccountModels.cs, I want to separate them to know they are related to app configuration so I have created another file called AppConfigModels.cs under Models folder which contains this (a piece of it):

```
public class ConfigContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfigContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Config1> Config1{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Config2> Config2{ get; set; }
}

(...) // tables definition
```

this is in the same namespace as the default one, and I want it to point to the same database as I want my app config table to be created in the same database.

By default entity framework is not going to update database if it is created so I rename the existing database or remove so entity framework creates again (I know I can change the behaviour to entity framework updates database if model changes but in this case i have proceeded as explained). So it starts and following on OnActionExecuting in file InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock); <---- HERE IT CRASHES
    }

    (...)
}
```

And the error raised is:

```
The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588
```

How to get rid of this? I want to keep separated my tables in a different file and point to the same database with another context.

Answer (score 4):

Arthur Vickers from Entity Framework team recommends the following pattern….

Instead of specifying separate connection strings in your app.config file for multiple context, just set one string and give it a generic name.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBContext" connectionString="Your conn string here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then create a base context class that will use the connection string:

```
using System.Data.Entity; 

    namespace DataLayer
    {
        public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
        {
            static BaseContext()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null); 
            }
            protected BaseContext()
                : base("name=MyDBContext")
            {
            }

        }
    }
```

Now, inherit this base behavior in each context (for instance):

```
namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    public class OrderContext : BaseContext<OrderContext>

…

namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    public class ProductContext : BaseContext<ProductContext>
…
```

Answer (score 1):

With EF5 if you put the contexts in separate projects you can use multiple migrations.

Use EF6 it supports [multiple contexts for DB](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations). EF4/5 doesn't like multiple contexts pointing at the same database within the same project.

Comment: What do you mean by "EF4/5 doesn't like multiple contexts pointing at the same database"?

Answer (score 0):

Does the database have the UsersProfile table set up? If not, the SimpleMembership won't initialize. The schema is below (not sure if this query will run):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile](
[UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [varchar](75) NOT NULL,
)
```